# Unable convert string date "dd-MM-yyyy" into a date for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I'm not able to convert the date passing to my pipe.
Seems like when I have a locale set up as 'nl-nl' and I want to format my date to 'dd-MM-YYYY' I'm getting an exception saying it is `Unable to convert "16-02-2023" into a date for pipe 'DatePipe'` for others work fine for instance `02-09-2023`

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../services/configuration.service';

@Pipe({
    name: 'formattedDate',
})
export class FormattedDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(
        private datePipe: DatePipe,
        private configurationService: ConfigurationService,
    ) {}

    transform(value: Date | string | number): string {
        return this.datePipe.transform(value, this.configurationService.config.customer.dateFormat);
    }
}
```

My assumption is that the part of day is taken for month and that's why it works only for some date, but I cannot figure out why it happens like that.

Comment: share the transform() function from DatePipe service please

Comment: It probably does something silly like `new Date(value)`; See one of the many questions we have for converting a string to a Date: [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript), etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Seems like my OS region format was set up English (US), so probably the format issue came from there. @HereticMonkey it helps me to handle it properly, thx.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../services/configuration.service';

@Pipe({
    name: 'formattedDate',
})
export class FormattedDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(
        private datePipe: DatePipe,
        private configurationService: ConfigurationService,
    ) {}

    transform(value: Date | string | number): string {
       
        return this.datePipe.transform(value, 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'nl-nl');
    }
}
```

To resolve the problem, ensure that the date format you're using aligns with the conventions of the 'nl-nl' locale. In the Netherlands, the standard date format is typically 'dd-MM-yyyy,' with the year represented in lowercase as 'yyyy,' rather than in uppercase as 'YYYY.' By adhering to these conventions, you can avoid errors when working with date formatting in the Dutch context.